# cv2.split() doesn't work beyond 512 channels

Tags: opencv, numpy

I have an array of size `(10x10x1000` and I want to split it into `1000 arrays of 10x10`. So I used `cv2.split()` function for that. But it doesn't work.

So, on close examination, I saw that cv2.split() doesn't work for arrays with **more than 512 channels.**

See below :

```
In [101]: j = np.arange(3*3*512).reshape((3,3,512)); k = cv2.split(j); print len(k)
512

In [102]: j = np.arange(3*3*513).reshape((3,3,513)); k = cv2.split(j); print len(k)
1
```

**What is the problem here ? Is it a bug or is there anything else to do to make it work ? Is there any other better methods to do this effectively ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open CV defines a maximum amount of channels with the variable CV_CN_MAX.

"The maximum possible number of channels is defined by the CV_CN_MAX constant, which is currently set to 512."  You can read that [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`numpy.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) instead:

```
>>> k = np.split(j, j.shape[-1], -1)
```

It seems to work:

```
>>> print len(k)
513
```

Comment: Thank you. I got to know about `np.dsplit` which does the same. Any idea what is the problem with cv2.split() function?